# Best Way To Store Tons of Data

Tags: ios, xcode, model-view-controller, objective-c++

I'm working on an application that will need to pull from a list of data depending on where the user is located in the US. In a sense, I will have a database full of information based on their location, and a condition statement will determine while value from the list to use.

Example of data:

**Tennessee:**

```
   Data2 = 25;
   Data3 = 58;
   ...
```

**Texas:**

```
   Data2 = 849;
   Data3 = 9292;
   ...
```

So on...

My question is, what is the best practice to use when developing iOS apps and you have a lot of data? Should you just put all the related data in a file, and import that file when you need to like normal, or is there another method you should use? I know they state you should follow the MVC practice, and I think in this case my data would be considered the Model, but just want to double check if that applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options here:

- SQLite database
- Core Data (its not a relational database model like sqlite)
- write to plain text file. (using NSFileManager )
- NSKeyedArchiever

If you want to frequently keep appending data to a single file, I would recommend using sqlite fast and robust.

Comment: Well I am going to manually input all the data, and may update the data as time progresses in the future, but not frequently. The users will not be able to access my data, and also, they should not have to access the internet in order to receive the data. I want all the data to be stored within the app itself. So I'm familar with SQL databases such as MySQL's graphical interface through phpmyadmin, but when it comes to Xcode and creating a SQL database, I do not have a clue where to start. My app will not constantly be accessing this data either, just FYI. Is SQL database still prefered?